# Existence of the Limit of a Two-Variable Function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

This problem is an example in my calculus textbook. Let:
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{y^2\sin^2(x)}{x^4+y^4}
$$
My textbook says that
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y) \text{ does not exist.}
$$
**Questions:**

1. How do we know the limit does not exist?
2. In general, suppose the limit of a function exists but we do not know the value of such limit, how do we find it?

Comment: Typically, to prove that the limit does not exist, people find distinct sublimits. If you know the limit exists and just want to find it, then you just need to consider an appropriate (read easy) sublimit.

Comment: @GitGud Does this mean that proving a limit does not exist, as in this question, might be very difficult if we cannot identify the proper sublimits, which more or less boils down to trial & error?

Comment: There are strategies you can use. For rational functions in two variables you can try looking at sublimits of the form $t\mapsto (t, kt)$, $t\mapsto (t, kt^2)$, $t\mapsto (t, kt^3)$ and so on, with varying values of $k$. If you're unable to find different sublimits, then perhaps the sublimit exists and you can try to focus on proving it does exist. When you don't have a rational function, you can probably use Taylor's theorem to get a similarly behaved rational function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the curves $\gamma_{1} = (t,t)$ and $\gamma_{2}(t) = (t,t^{2})$. Thus we have
\begin{align*}f(\gamma_{1}(t)) = \frac{t^{2}\sin^{2}(t)}{t^{4} + t^{4}} = \frac{\sin^{2}(t)}{2t^{2}} \Longrightarrow \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f(\gamma_{1}(t)) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right)^{2}\right] = \frac{1}{2} 
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have
\begin{align*}
f(\gamma_{2}(t)) = \frac{t^{8}\sin^{2}(t)}{t^{4} + t^{8}} = \frac{t^{4}\sin^{2}(t)}{1 + t^{4}} \Longrightarrow \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f(\gamma_{2}(t)) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{t^{4}\sin^{2}(t)}{1+t^{4}} = \frac{0\times 0}{1+0} = 0
\end{align*}

If the given limit existed, we should have $\displaystyle\lim_{t\rightarrow0}f(\gamma_{1}(t)) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f(\gamma_{2}(t))$. Hence $\displaystyle\lim_{\textbf{x}\rightarrow\textbf{0}} f(\textbf{x})$ does not exist. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! What is your general strategy for finding these two curves as in this example?

Comment: As previously mentioned, there is  no general strategy. In this particular case, such choices were made because they "break the symmetry".

Comment: For this example, could you explain to me more how the two curves "break the symmetry"? I never heard of that before.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an English native speaker. What I actually meant is: choose two curves whose limits of $f(\gamma_{k}(t))$ are different as $t\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: What if finding such two curves is difficult? For example, what do you do if the limit doesn't exist but all the curves you have found produce the same limit? Is keeping trying our only option?

Comment: There are other possible approaches to tackle this kind of problem. Consider, for example, the function

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$$

Since $\displaystyle 0 \leq \frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}} \leq 1$ and $y^{2}\rightarrow 0$ as $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$, according to the squeeze theorem, we have

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)} f(x,y) = 0$$

Comment: Can you explain more how you used the squeeze theorem in this example?

Comment: Notice that $\displaystyle\left|\frac{x^{2}y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\leq y^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

1:  Use the approximation (for small $x), \ sin(x)\approx x$.  Then $f(x,y)\approx \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}$.  Now consider two cases:

(a) $x=y$ then the function  $=\frac{1}{2}$.

(b) $x=0$ or $y=0$ where the function $=0$, when the other variable $\ne 0$.

Therefore the limit does not exist.

2: There is no general solution.  Each problem must be evaluated on its own.